# Manually compile using gcc -v

Tags: c, gcc

Is it possible to compile a simple Hello World program that only uses provided gcc/glibc files rather than using the default ones provided by the OS ? (Therefore, when executed, the program will only use the provided files rather than the ones the OS provides.) I've looked everywhere on the net but cannot get any to work:

I tried to manually do what this does **gcc -v simple.c** but I cannot reproduce it myself.

This is what I tried: (all provided files are on the Desktop)

```
 /home/myuser/Desktop/cc1 -quiet -v simple.c -quiet -dumpbase simple.c -mtune=generic -auxbase simple -version -o /tmp/temp1.s
```

How can the below paths be changed to custom ones rather than default ones ?

```
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include  search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C (Debian 4.4.5-8) version 4.4.5 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.4.5, GMP version 4.3.2, MPFR version 3.0.0-p3.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: dac4d891d068d1bed01868869b00bd17
```

```
as -V -Qy -o /tmp/temp2.o /tmp/temp1.s
```

```
GNU assembler version 2.20.1 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.20.1-system.20100303
```

```
/home/myuser/Desktop/collect2 --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=both -dynamic-linker ld-2.11.2.so crt1.o crti.o crtbegin.o /tmp/temp2.o libgcc.a --as-needed libgcc_s.so.1 --no-as-needed libc.a libgcc_s.so.1 --as-needed libgcc.a --no-as-needed crtend.o crtn.o
```

Why is the below /usr/bin/ld used instead of the provided ld-2.11.2.so ?

```
/usr/bin/ld: dynamic STT_GNU_IFUNC symbol `strcmp' with pointer equality in `libc.a(strcmp.o)' can not be used when making an executable; recompile with -fPIE and relink with -pie
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can anybody modify it to work ?

Answer (score 0):

`-v` shows you the actions performed by the compiler driver. It does not affect what standard libraries you get.

To run with all custom libraries, use `-nostdlib`.

Comment: I tried this and it does not work either: gcc -nostdlib /home/myuser/Desktop/libgcc.a /home/myuser/Desktop/libc.a simple.c /usr/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000400144
/tmp/ccDFp8hh.o: In function `main':
simple.c:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `memcpy'
simple.c:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `puts'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @Janet: You need to precede the library pathnames with `-l`, eg `-l/home/myuser/Desktop/libgcc.a`.

Answer (score 0):

> How can the below paths be changed to
>   custom ones rather than default ones ?

Simply add `-I path` to the compiler call. This path will be added before the internal paths.

> Why is the below /usr/bin/ld used
>   instead of the provided ld-2.11.2.so ?

The first one is an executable binary, the second one is a shared object. You can't use a shared object in a place of a binary.

Comment: @Janet You mean the linking error? That is because you are not compiling with position independent executable support. But I assumed that this is what you are trying to do. `-I` of course only modifies the include paths. And of course include paths have nothing to do with linking. Please try to explain what you are trying to achieve. It is not clear from your question.